# Iptables failed in Yocto image running docker compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, yocto, iptables

After seeing several posts in stackoverflow and some other blogs, I still couldn't get rid of some `iptables` issue.

I created a `Yocto` image (x86) with the following recipe:

```
require recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb

DESCRIPTION = "My Linux Image."

IMAGE_INSTALL += "\
    docker-ce  \
    python3-docker-compose \
    python3 \
    "
```

My environment is `Windows 10` with `WSL2` where I have `Ubuntu 22.04` running with `QEMU` emulator.

I just want to create a simple Linux image with `docker compose` where I could be able to run the `hello-world` from `docker compose`:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

I am blocked on this:

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint docker-compose-hello-world-web-1 (149593c5ce28171b7a379f9a5b896e3a541c6ab89fda6):
(iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 9999 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.3:5000 ! -i br-fc6bc88aac23: 
Warning: Extension DNAT revision 0 not supported, missing kernel module?
```

I am exposing the port `9999` from my `docker-compose.yml`.

What module my kernel is missing?
I've already tried to restart the docker service, reboot, etc, you name it.
I've tried to add these env variables as well:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0
```

My docker network is this:

```
root@qemux86-64:~/docker-compose-hello-world# docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                                 DRIVER    SCOPE
e0109904a4f1   bridge                               bridge    local
ee1bf049614b   docker-compose-hello-world_default   bridge    local
1c399dc89e34   host                                 host      local
a3994241998d   none                                 null      local
root@qemux86-64:~/docker-compose-hello-world#
```

What kernel module could be missing here?